# Why isn't this method documentation linking to the directive documentation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsdoc

I am using JsDoc 3.3.0 with ngdoc.

I have the following directive documentation:

```
/**
* description
*
* @ngdoc directive
* @name  directiveName
* @restrict AE
*/
```

and the following method documentation within that directive:

```
/**
 * method description
 *
 * @ngdoc method
 * @name methodName
 * @methodOf directiveName
 */
```

The output HTML displays the directive in the directives list, but the method appears under "Global". Why does the method not appear as part of the directive instead?

I have been using [this](http://www.podpea.co.uk/blog/starting-off-with-ngdocs/) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation) as references in trying to get this to work.

Comment: Turns out "@memberof" works, but "@methodOf" doesn't. Will leave this question open in case there's a better solution.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to add that as an answer to your own question, so that others can see the answer clearly later if that turns out to be the best (or only) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that replacing "@methodOf" with "@memberOf" solves the issue for now.